# Google Distance Matrix API substituting address that isn't even close

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

When I search for '160 Trek Ln, Redding, CA 96003', the Distance Matrix changes my search to 'Bechelli Ln at Hartnell Ave, Redding, CA 96002, USA'. I know that '160 Trek Ln, Redding, CA 96003' doesn't exist yet in Google Maps, but changing the address to something else completely different is definitely not what I want. Getting some kind of error 'Address not found' or something would be better.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Internally Distance Matrix uses Geocoding to resolve the address to coordinate. It will try to get best match even for non-existing address, in your case it gives partial match. I believe there is no way to change this behavior of service. If you know exact coordinate of your address use it instead of address string. In this case Distance Matrix will snap to nearest road directly without geocoding step and you may get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Internally Distance Matrix uses Geocoding to resolve the address to coordinate. It will try to get best match even for non-existing address, in your case it gives partial match. I believe there is no way to change this behavior of service. If you know exact coordinate of your address use it instead of address string. In this case Distance Matrix will snap to nearest road directly without geocoding step and you may get better results." – xomena Aug 29 at 20:48